# Is there a canonical or good way to define a non-busy-wait Future in Scala that never ends?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I need to define a mutable Future used as a UI callback. When created, it shouldn't complete until it is assigned an actual computation, so something like this:

```
var myCallback: Future[Option[Long]] = Future.dummyWait
```

Of course, I could do the following, but that would be a busy wait:

```
var myCallback: Future[Option[Long]] = Future{while(true){0;}; Some(0L)}
```

If Future isn't the right abstraction, what is?

Comment: Actually, this is stupid - I just realized it won't work - when the UI probes myCallback, it might get the old `dummyWait` Future, which will never have a meaningful value. The perils of mutability!

Comment: It seems a Promise is likely the correct abstraction.

Comment: Whould it never be completed or just delayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct abstraction for a *to be completed* `Future` is a `Promise`:

```
val p = Promise[Option[Long]]()
val myCallback: Future[Option[Long]] = p.future

// Somewhere else in your code, this can trigger myCallback completion:
p.success(Some(42L))
```